# How do I use non-admin theme for page containing node form?

Tags: 8, routes

I've created a custom route where I return node add form with a controller. It works fine, but for the administrator user it is using the administrator theme. 
I tried using the following, but it doesn't help.

```
  options:
    _admin_route: FALSE
```

Is there a good approach to achieve this? As I remember, in Drupal 7, it worked fine with `hook_admin_paths()`.

Comment: You've done it correctly - did you clear your cache after doing this?

Comment: @Jaypan yes, sure

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because bugs are of topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the issue was related to the bug in metatag module, it was in version 8.x-1.0-beta11.

It caused break of my routes when they ended with `/add`. It was trying to handle prefix of path as entity type, so my routes worked fine only if I had `_node_operation_route: TRUE` in route options. But if this option is set `_admin_route: TRUE` is added by core.

I updated metatag module to the latest version (8.x-1.0 currently) and found they've added check for existing entity type, so I'm not forced to use `_node_operation_route: TRUE` anymore and I'm able to output custom routes in a default site theme.